# How to add Screensaver Settings via Registry file

Tags: registry, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I'm working in a large organization and we have to go around to about 150 computers and manually change the screensaver settings. The way our AD is setup, I cannot distribute this through Group Policy. I'm trying to make a reg file to make this faster. I want the screensaver on Windows 10 to be 3D Text, wait 230 minutes, and uncheck "On resume, display logon screen"

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaveActive"="1"
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="0"
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="13800"
"SCRNSAVE.EXE"="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ssText3d.scr"
"LockScreenAutoLockActive"="0"
```

Seems like only the "SCRNSAVE.EXE"="C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssText3d.scr" line worked.
The others did not get implemented when running this reg file.